# multiple fields Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists

Tags: php, zend-framework

This is my table schema, which have composite key (username,emailid,phone)

How to validate similar record not exist in the table.

Example

```
username         emailid       phone      
abc            test@one.com   123456789    
abc            test@one.com   123456789
abc            test2@one.com  123456789
abc            test@one.com   456789269
abc            test2@one.com  456789269
abc            test@one.com   123456789
```

How restrict last record inserted inthe above table.

validation should perform under three fields record.

Comment: You need to create a custom one for such purpose. And in that fire a count query with using this three fields.

Comment: so cant we do this logic with Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists

Comment: Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059705/zend-validate-db-recordexists-against-2-fields).